# How to take away health points when using a class?

Tags: python

I'm working on a game in python and I can't figure out how to take away health once attack function has taken place. I can run the program and the attack function works fine, it shows a random integer between 1 and 50 but doesn't actually take away health from `castlehealth` = 100

Underneath  `print("You attacked for " + str(self.attack))` I left the next line blank because I don't know what to type in, I tried a lot of different things and just can't get  the attack to take away from `castlehealth`.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
from random import randint

class GameActions:
    def __init__(self):
        castlehealth = 100
        self.castlehealth = castlehealth
    def health(self):
        print("Castle health is: " + str(self.castlehealth))
        print()
    def attack(self):
        attack = randint(0, 50)
        self.attack = attack
        print("You attacked for " + str(self.attack))

def game():
    while True:
        game_actions = GameActions()
        print("What do you want to do?")
        print()
        print("attack, view hp")
        ans = input()
        if ans == "hp":
            game_actions.health()
        if ans == "attack":
            game_actions.attack()
```

Comment: What is it that you're attacking?  The castle?  You subtract the attack amount from whatever variable contains the HP of the thing you attacked.

Comment: 1. Fix your indents: "def health"  should be within "class GameActions". 2. be careful about doing "self.attack = ..."; you're overwriting the function "self.attack". 3: self.castlehealth -= attack

Comment: Is it just me or is `while True: game_actions = GameActions()` a really bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

You want the following:

```
self.castlehealth -= attack
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `self.castlehealth -= attack`. I also fixed some potential indentation issues for you.

Your full code sample could look this this:

```
import os
import time
from random import randint

class GameActions:
    def __init__(self):
        castlehealth = 100
        self.castlehealth = castlehealth
    def health(self):
        print("Castle health is: " + str(self.castlehealth))
        print()
    def attack(self):
        attack = randint(0, 50)
        self.attack = attack
        print("You attacked for " + str(self.attack))
        self.castlehealth -= attack

def game():
    while True:
        game_actions = GameActions()
        print("What do you want to do?")
        print()
        print("attack, view hp")
        ans = input()
        if ans == "hp":
           game_actions.health()
        if ans == "attack":
           game_actions.attack()
```

Explanation: `self.castlehealth` is an instance variable of your `GameActions` class. The function `GameActions.attack()` creates a new `attack` variable as a random integer and then subtracts that value from the instance variable `self.castlehealth` of the `GameActions` class. Now `self.castlehealth` will be the updated value. Consider also tracking the various attacks and resulting healths in a data structure, since every time you have a new `attack` `self.castlehealth` and `self.attack` will change values and you will lose the ability to access the previous values.